# javascript eventlistener fire immediately instead of on event

Tags: javascript, events, onclicklistener

I am trying to use an `EventListener` method with `click` event to simply add one element to `<ul>` list. I am trying to invoke the function with `click` event on button element's node, but the function is being invoked every time I refresh/load a website.

```
function addElementToList() {
    var navigationPanel = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];

    var newElementOnList = document.createElement('li');
    var newElementsText = document.createTextNode('About');

    newElementOnList.appendChild(newElementsText);
    navigationPanel.appendChild(newElementOnList);
}

var elButton = document.getElementById('myButton');
elButton.addEventListener('click', addElementToList(), false);
```

Why is the function `addElementToList` running every time I refresh/load a website?

Comment: `elButton.addEventListener('click', addElementToList, false);`

Answer (score 3):

When adding the event listener,

```
elButton.addEventListener('click', addElementToList(), false);
```

You are calling the function.  change to

```
elButton.addEventListener('click', addElementToList, false);
```

And you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is adding the result of addElementToList (as the function is actually being called) to the event listener. Not the method itself.

To put the method itself you want to use the name with no brackets

```
elButton.addEventListener('click', addElementToList, false);
```

instead of

```
elButton.addEventListener('click', addElementToList(), false);
```

Comment: Thanks :) One question though. What would happen if I'd have a function that requires parameters to be given like addElementToList(par a, par b)? I assume function with parameters would not return a result immediately right?

Comment: it would be run immediately the parameters will be `undefined`. parameter in JS is mostly a suggestion and not a requirement